# OpenCv C++ Perspective Transform

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I am trying to use OpenCv to correct an image for distortion and then calculate the real world coordinates given a pixel coordinate. I can not find any examples online or in the OpenCv book of how to do this.

I have done the camera calibration with the chess board image. Now, I just need a basic function that I can give pixel coordinates to that will give me real world coordinates based off of the camera matrix, the distortion coefficients, rotational and translation vectors.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: To project onto the chessboard plane, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14602271/1755482).

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at the `findHomography()` function. If you know the location in the real world of a set of points you can use this function to create transformation matrix that you can use with the function `perspectiveTransform()`

```
std::vector<Point2f> worldPoints;
std::vector<Point2f> cameraPoints;

//insert somepoints in both vectors

Mat perspectiveMat_= findHomography(cameraPoints, worldPoints, CV_RANSAC);

//use perspective transform to translate other points to real word coordinates

std::vector<Point2f> camera_corners;
//insert points from your camera image here

std::vector<Point2f> world_corners;
perspectiveTransform(camera_corners, world_corners, perspectiveMat_);
```

You can find more information about the function [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html)

Comment: @dilip_thomas How can I find the real world points? I need to know that to pass it to the findHomography function.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand correctly you need a world point from image point. With a monocular camera this problem is unsolvable. You can not determine the depth (distance) of the real world point to the camera.

There are visual simultaneous localization and mapping (SLAM) algorithms that create a map of the world and compute the trajectory of the camera from a video, but they are a whole other thing.

Answer (score 1):

Given a single image and a point on it, expressed in terms of 2D pixel coordinates, there is an infinity of 3D points in the real world, all belonging to a line, which map to your point in your image... not just one point.

Answer (score -1):

But, if you know the distance of the object in pixel (x,y) from the camera then you can calculate its location in 3D.